# How to get all video files from google drive with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-api, google-drive-api

How can I get all video file list from my google drive after login?

```
var client = GoogleHttpClient(await googleSignInAccount.authHeaders);
var drive = ga.DriveApi(client);
  drive.files.list(spaces: 'appDataFolder').then((value) {
  setState(() {
    list = value;
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < list.files.length; i++) {
    print("Id: ${list.files[i].id} File Name:${list.files[i].name}");
  }
});
```

I have just gone through this video(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9kXov_Ly9BI) and created an application. In that video, it shows me how to upload the files to google drive and I want to get the all list of video file from my google drive.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Without showing what you have already tried and where you stuck, you will most likely get no answer here.

Comment: What's prevent you from using the Google Drive API?

Comment: @mezoni Thank you. I have no experience using Google Drive API with flutter because i just started learning for Google Drive API.

Comment: @NayThitHtoo, you can try the [googleapis](https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis) package if you want to work with Google Drive.